# Проблема с CheckBox-ами. Программа вылетает на устройстве

Tags: java, android, android-studio, checkbox

Суть такова: должно быть 2 основных чекбоксы (Loaded и Empty), и 2 чекбоксы, которые будут появляться при выборе Loaded - Depart и Arrive. Когда были только Loaded и Empty все работало нормально, но когда добавил Depart и Arrive, теперь работает только Empty. При выборе Loaded программа вылетает. Не понимаю в чем причина.

**Метод в активити:**

```
public void robotTypeOfLoadingCheckbox(View view) {
    CheckBox robotTypeOfLoading = (CheckBox) view;
    boolean checked = robotTypeOfLoading.isChecked();

    TextView selection = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.robot_shipment_selection);

    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.loaded:
            if (checked) {
//                  selection.setText("Loaded");
                view.findViewById(R.id.depart).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                view.findViewById(R.id.arrive).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                switch (view.getId()) {
                    case R.id.depart:
                        if (checked) {
                            selection.setText("Depart");
                        }
                        break;
                    case R.id.arrive:
                        if (checked) {
                            selection.setText("Arrive");
                        }
                        break;
                }
                break;
            }
        case R.id.empty:
            if (checked)
                selection.setText("Empty");
            break;
    }
}
```

**Содержимое XML-файла:**

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/shipment_activity"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="16dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/robot_shipment_selection"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="26sp" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/loaded"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Loaded"
    android:textSize="26sp"
    android:onClick="robotTypeOfLoadingCheckbox"/>

<CheckBox android:id="@+id/depart"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Depart"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:textSize="26sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:onClick="robotTypeOfLoadingCheckbox"/>

<CheckBox android:id="@+id/arrive"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Arrive"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:textSize="26sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:onClick="robotTypeOfLoadingCheckbox"/>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/empty"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Empty"
    android:textSize="26sp"
    android:onClick="robotTypeOfLoadingCheckbox"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Скриншоты с устройства**
[image: Работает][image: Вылетает]

Comment: Посмотрите в логе какую ошибку выдает

Comment: @Pollux , Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.nulp.robotcontoller.ShipmentActivity.robotTypeOfLoadingCheckbox(ShipmentActivity.java:28) 
Это строка: view.findViewById(R.id.depart).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: @Pollux на null не знаю как проверить. Разделил на два шага, ругаеться на .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по вашему коду, у вас `view` - это сам чекбокс. И вы в нем  ищете еще чекбокс: `view.findViewById(R.id.depart)`.

Уберите `view.`

Comment: спасибо, помогло!)

Comment: для Depart и Arrive еще не срабатывает selection.setText(). Можете подсказать в чем тут дело?(в случае с Empty срабатывает)

Comment: Посмотрите ваше условие `switch`. У вас их нажатие проверяется только в случае нажатия на `loaded`, то есть никогда не срабатывает :) Вынесите их за `case loaded:`

Comment: понял, большое спасибо!